# A different variation of the double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference

What would be the image created by light if we do the "double-slit experiment" with a wall which has more than two slits, and what happens when we take the number of slits to infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently phrased, the question is describing a [diffraction grating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating), which consists of $N$ point-source slits separated from each other by some fixed distance $d$. In short, adding more point sources will tend to make the interference pattern sharper, i.e. the destructive-interference regions will become wider, and the constructive-interference regions will become more and more localized.

[image]

In the limit where you have infinite slits, the interference peaks become infinitely sharp (and infinitely thin), i.e. they approach a series of Dirac deltas. Or, put another way, the Fourier transform of a Dirac comb is another Dirac comb, a fact often known as the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

---

If, instead, you add slits all over the wall so that the wall is covered in slits, as implied in [some](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38827871#38827871) of your comments in chat, then what you're describing is a [window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window) which is fully transparent. If it is lit from behind by a collimated beam of light, it will let through a collimated beam of light.

---

<sup>Mathematica code for the image: `Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaMZp.png"]`</sup>